# MySQL subquery JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to put together a single SQL query that will grab COUNT values from one table, and an AVG of a SUM from another. The two queries work separately, but I can't figure out how to properly JOIN them into one.

The two queries -- the first having been shortened to two sums:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `eventClass`='GOAL' AND `player1ID`=001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) goals,
SUM(CASE WHEN `eventClass`='GOAL' AND `player2ID`=001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) assists
FROM `plays`
```

&

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(`toi`)) AS avgTime 
FROM ( 
    SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`shiftDuration`)) AS toi 
    FROM `shifts` 
    WHERE `playerID`=001 
    GROUP BY `gameNo`
) t;
```

Now I've tried a few things for the join, but am not sure on what to join them, as I in the first query I am looking for my search value 001 in one of two columns, depending on the row.

Much obliged to any help!

Andrew

---

SAMPLE DATA:

```
table `plays`:
+--------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| playNo | gameNo | eventClass | player1ID | player2ID |
+--------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|      1 |      1 |   GOAL     |   001     |    002    |
|    210 |      3 |   GOAL     |   003     |    001    |
+--------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+

table `shifts`:
+---------+--------+----------+---------------+
| shiftNo | gameNo | playerID | shiftDuration |
+---------+--------+----------+---------------+
|       1 |      1 |   001    |      65       |
|       2 |      1 |   001    |      38       |
|      12 |      1 |   002    |      47       |
|      22 |      3 |   001    |      13       |
+------=--+--------+----------+---------------+
```

Now I want to take the sum of all player 001 shifts in a game, for the game total; it is the average of all these game totals for 001 that I'd like to output.

Desired output -- goals and assists are all-game TOTALS for 001, whereas avgTime is a per-game AVERAGE. Here we'll mark it in seconds.

```
+-------+-------+---------+---------+
| games | goals | assists | avgTime |
+-------+-------+---------+---------+
|   3   |  2    |   1     |   800   |
+-------+-------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: How are `plays` and `shifts` related to each other?  What would `JOIN` operation actually accomplish?

Comment: You will need to consider what you are trying to accomplish.  I'm assuming you are trying to select goals and assists by player...as this sits, it's only valid for player one.  Consider adding playerID in the select column of your first query and group by it as well.  Change your second query to select player and group by player...then join on playerID.

Comment: @PM77-1 `plays` and `shifts` are two separate tables, the first containing all plays in a specific game, the second containing all individual shifts of players in a game. I'm trying to collect, as a single row, a number of statistics relating to a single player over several games From `plays` I can get the sum of goals, assists, what have you, but only from `shifts` can I get the average time on ice (hockey, here). So I'm trying to join this average time value onto the end of my other statistics. (Many thanks for the response)

Comment: You have not identified `PRIMARY` and `FOREIGN` keys yet.

Comment: Thanks for the resopnse @Twelfth -- thing is that there are multiple `playerID`s involved in a given `play`, whereas only one is assigned to each `shift`. In having a single `playerID` column I wouldn't be able to access all players in the play... or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @PM77-1 -- My primary keys in each table are auto-increment ID keys that are unrelated to player identification. `FOREIGN` keys I hadn't heard of before, but like I was saying to Twelfth I'll need access to all (up to 3) players in a given `play`.

Comment: @Andrew - want to give a sample of the data in plays and shifts and what your desired output is (edit your question and include it)?  It'll help me understand what you're looking for a bit better

Comment: @Twelfth Sample data and ideal output added. If MySQL was ok with having and `AND` in between the two above `SELECT` statements I'd be laughing and free. Alas.

Comment: @Twelfth Alternatively, I've been toying with the idea of adding game totals to a separate pre-existing table that serves as an index of which players played in which game -- i.e. there is one row per player, per game. This table has no more than 50k rows, whereas `plays` can have up to 400k. Would I be better off with this?

Comment: Is the goals broken out as playerID1 = goal, playerID 2 = assist?  Is there a second assist on goals?

Comment: @Twelfth There is a second assist on goals in a third column, but for the sake of simplicity I mentioned only two. In any case ol' Gord below has figured it out! Thanks for the help. May go with the separate table regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using subqueries or `cross join`?

```
SELECT p.goals, p.assist, s.avgTime
FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN `eventClass`='GOAL' AND `player1ID`=001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) goals,
             SUM(CASE WHEN `eventClass`='GOAL' AND `player2ID`=001 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) assists
      FROM `plays`
     ) p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ROUND(AVG(`toi`)) AS avgTime 
      FROM (SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`shiftDuration`)) AS toi 
            FROM `shifts` 
            WHERE `playerID`=001 
            GROUP BY `gameNo`
           ) s
     ) s;
```

It is not clear to me where the `games` column is coming from.

Don't attempt to do this with just `join`s and a single aggregation.  You are summarizing along two different dimensions -- and doing joins before aggregations tends to cause unwanted cartesian products.

Comment: Bravo Gordon! This works! I had looked into doing a `CROSS JOIN` but didn't use the proper syntax. This is perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as compact as @GordonLinoff but does handle more than one player at a time, and breaks down by individual game:

```
SELECT R.gameNo, R.playerID, R.goals, R.assists, S.toi FROM (
  SELECT P1.gameNo, P1.playerID, P1.goals, P2.assists FROM (
    SELECT
      gameNo
      , player1ID playerID
      , COUNT(playNo) goals
    FROM Plays
    WHERE eventClass = 'GOAL'
    GROUP BY gameNo, player1ID
  ) P1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      gameNo
      , player2ID playerID
      , COUNT(playNo) assists
    FROM Plays
    WHERE eventClass = 'GOAL'
    GROUP BY gameNo, player2ID
  ) P2 ON P1.gameNo = P2.gameNo AND P1.playerID = P2.playerID
  UNION
  SELECT P2.gameNo, P2.playerID, P1.goals, P2.assists FROM (
    SELECT
      gameNo
      , player1ID playerID
      , COUNT(playNo) goals
    FROM Plays
    WHERE eventClass = 'GOAL'
    GROUP BY gameNo, player1ID
  ) P1
  RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT
      gameNo
      , player2ID playerID
      , COUNT(playNo) assists
    FROM Plays
    WHERE eventClass = 'GOAL'
    GROUP BY gameNo, player2ID
  ) P2 ON P1.gameNo = P2.gameNo AND P1.playerID = P2.playerID
) R
JOIN (
  SELECT
    gameNo
    , playerID
    , SUM(shiftDuration) AS toi 
  FROM Shifts
  GROUP BY gameNo, playerID
) S
ON R.gameNo = S.gameNo AND R.playerID = S. playerID
ORDER BY gameNo, playerID
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77e6e1/1/3)

I dropped `TIME_TO_SEC` (which to me doesn't seem to have any effect - based on the given data), and did not `AVG` in order to return the time played in the respective game.

But apparently, you wanted overall totals (and thus `AVG`). So - this should be the answer to your question:

```
SELECT R.playerID, R.goals, R.assists, S.avgTime FROM (
  SELECT P1.playerID, P1.goals, P2.assists FROM (
    SELECT
      player1ID playerID
      , COUNT(playNo) goals
    FROM Plays
    WHERE eventClass = 'GOAL'
    GROUP BY player1ID
  ) P1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      player2ID playerID
      , COUNT(playNo) assists
    FROM Plays
    WHERE eventClass = 'GOAL'
    GROUP BY player2ID
  ) P2 ON P1.playerID = P2.playerID
  UNION
  SELECT P2.playerID, P1.goals, P2.assists FROM (
    SELECT
      player1ID playerID
      , COUNT(playNo) goals
    FROM Plays
    WHERE eventClass = 'GOAL'
    GROUP BY gameNo, player1ID
  ) P1
  RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT
      player2ID playerID
      , COUNT(playNo) assists
    FROM Plays
    WHERE eventClass = 'GOAL'
    GROUP BY player2ID
  ) P2 ON P1.playerID = P2.playerID
) R
JOIN (
    SELECT S.playerID, ROUND(AVG(S.toi)) avgTime
    FROM (
      SELECT
        gameNo
        , playerID
        , SUM(shiftDuration) AS toi 
      FROM Shifts
      GROUP BY gameNo, playerID
    ) S
    GROUP BY S.playerID
) S
ON R.playerID = S. playerID
ORDER BY R.playerID
;
```

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77e6e1/17/4)

The fiddles start with the individual parts of the above statements, and advance to the complete assembly.